# MVC 2- Updating Model Data when model is of type IEnumerable/IQueryable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

Controller Code:

```
Function ManagePages() As ActionResult
    Dim pages = contentRepository.GetAllContentPagesByType("Content Page", False)
    Return View("ManagePages", pages)
End Function

<HttpPost()> _
Function ManagePages(ByVal values As FormCollection) As ActionResult
    Dim pages = contentRepository.GetAllContentPagesByType("Content Page", False)
    ''' **** HOW DO I UPDATE THE MODEL HERE ****
    contentRepository.Save() 'Simply calls SubmitChanges()
    Return View("ManagePages", pages)
End Function
```

GetAllContentPagesByType returns an IQueryable - the result of a LINQ-to-SQL query.  The view is strongly typed:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IQueryable (Of DBContent))"
```

I am looping through each of the DBContent objects in the view and creating textboxes and other inputs for a few properties - basically I am displaying an editor for each record in the Model.  This works fine.

Now I've tried many different ways to get this to update:

- Calling UpdateModel() then
  SubmitChanges() on the LINQ data
  context - did nothing.
- Followed Phil
  Haack's "Binding to List" tutorial,
  but it doesn't go in depth as far as
  updating the model: 
  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx
- Used variations of parameter types
  into the HttpPost for ManagePages to
  no avail.

The only way I can think of now to get it to work would be to loop through all of the items in the FormCollection parameter, and manually update each DBContent record in the collection, but that doesn't seem like a best practice solution.

The question is - what is the gold standard best practice for this scenario to update a model of any enumerable type?

**Edit**

If it helps, here a code snippet for the view.  Note that using Html.TextBox, etc, doesn't seem to affect the resulting form data.  I'm always getting 4 form keys, with comma-separated values (one for each property basically).  I've tried prepending these with the record ID (unique key), but UpdateModel() still doesn't work, though I do get a unique form value for each input control:

```
<% Using Html.BeginForm%>
    <%  For Each item In Model.OrderBy(Function(c) c.DisplayOrder)%>
    <%: Html.Hidden("ContentId", Model.ContentId.ToString())%>
    <tr>
        <td class="first"><input name='Enabled' type="checkbox" checked='<%: If(Model.Enabled, "checked", "")%>' /></td>
        <td class="first"><input name='DisplayOrder' type="text" value='<%: Model.DisplayOrder %>' style="width:40px" /></td>
        <td class="first"><select name='ContentLevel'>
            <option value="100" selected='<%: If(Model.ContentLevel = 100, "selected", "") %>'>Admin</option>
            <option value="50" selected='<%: If(Model.ContentLevel = 50, "selected", "") %>'>Board</option>
            <option value="25" selected='<%: If(Model.ContentLevel = 25, "selected", "") %>'>Member</option>
            <option value="0" selected='<%: If(Model.ContentLevel = 0, "selected", "") %>'>Everyone</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><a href="EditPage/<%: Model.ContentId %>"><%: Model.PageTitle%></a></td>
        <td><%: Model.aspnet_User.UserName%></td>
        <td class="last"><%: Model.ModifiedOn%></td>
    </tr>
    <%  Next%>
<% End Using%>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the real issue is you seem to be wanting to update the data from the view? The view is only capable of outputting HTML and related content. If you want the changes to be persisted, you need to make a request back to the server to an action that will apply the changed values.

Comment: The view has a simple submit button: `<input type="submit" value="Submit Updates" />` - Clicking this will trigger the <HttpPost()> ManagePages(formCollection) method.  In this method is where we traditionally call UpdateModel() for most objects, however lists need to be handled differently apparently.

Comment: Ah nevermind, sorry I missed that part in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going the route of giving each control a unique name, as per Phil Haack's post, starting with index "[0.]" as the prefix.  I then changed my Action method to accept a `List(of DBContent)`, which correctly bound the model data.  I was then able to manually loop through the collection, and manually update each record.

Answer (score 0):

You simply never make the call to UpdateModel to update the collection.

```
<HttpPost()> _
Function ManagePages(ByVal values As FormCollection) As ActionResult
    Dim pages = contentRepository.GetAllContentPagesByType("Content Page", False)

    UpdateModel(pages)

    contentRepository.Save() 'Simply calls SubmitChanges()
    Return View("ManagePages", pages)
End Function
```

You need to follow the instructions here:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Your `<input>`  elements name attributes need to follow a particular syntax for this to work.

Comment: UpdateModel() does nothing, as I mentioned above.  No errors at all either.

Comment: I've added more info to my question, including a code snippet for the view.